# Stored procedure returning dynamic columns in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework, linq, dynamic-expression

I have a function calling a SQL Server stored procedure using Entity Framework 6.2.

The stored procedure returns a result set which has different number of columns on each call, and column names may vary on each call.

```
Function getListOfDocs() As JsonResult
            Try
                Using entities As PromatEntities = New PromatEntities()

                    Dim param(1) As SqlParameter

                    param(0) = New SqlParameter("@ProjID", SqlDbType.Int)
                    param(0).Value = vProjectId

                    Dim query = entities.Database.SqlQuery(Of "help required here")("sp_EIP_IPSSDocMaster_Get", param) // cannot handle this case as entity framework needs type
                    Dim lstDocs = query.ToList
                End Using
                Return Json(New With {lstDocs}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
            Catch ex As Exception
                ClsCommon.ExceptionManager(ex)
                Return Nothing
            End Try
        End Function
```

But Entity Framework doesn't allow anonymous types in `database.SqlQuery`. Can anyone suggest a way to solve the issue and get the anonymous type data to view?

Comment: A stored procedure should **always** return the same "shape" of data - the same structure of the result set - otherwise you're in for a world of heartache and maintenance pain ..... If you have a stored procedure that returns multiple "shapes" of results - then your stored procedure is **doing too much** and should be split up into n separate stored procedures, each returning **one shape** of result (according to the Single Responsibility Principle of good software design)

Comment: EF Doesn't support that.  You can use an ADO.NET DataTable, or use Dapper and return a dynamic object.

Comment: I have the same case I’m working with pivot table so the results will not come with same shape so @marc_s there is a need of this unless you have different suggestion